# GWT Piechart setting specific slice color

Tags: gwt

I am new at GWT-Vizualisation, so i created a Pie-chart with its own colors. I could set my own colors to the chart.

```
        JsArrayString colors = JavaScriptObject.createArray().cast();
    colors.push("Red");
    colors.push("Green");
    options.setColors(colors);
```

But i can not set a color to specific slice of this chart. 
Is it any way to do this? 
I spend a lot of hours to find an answer, but i could not.

Comment: try `options.set('colors',colors);`

Comment: The method setColors(JsArrayString) only excepted a JsArrayString and how schould i define, that for value X it should be define  the color Y ?

Answer (score 0):

With google chart tools there are two ways how you can define the color of the individual slices (see [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart)):

- Array of objects: `slices: [{color: 'black', {}, {}, {color: 'red'}]`
- Objects with nested objects: `slices: {0: {color: 'black'}, 3: {color: 'red'}}`

You are using the wrong method. `setColors()` does not set the color of the individual slices.

You have to do it this way (method 1):

```
PieChart.Options options = PieChart.Options.create();
JsArray<Options> slices = JsArray.createArray().cast();  
Options slice1 = Options.create();
Options slice2 = Options.create();
Options slice3 = Options.create();
slice1.set("color":"black");
slice3.set("color":"red");
slices.push(slice1);
slices.push(slice2);
slices.push(slice3);
options.set("slices",slices);
```